# use setselectedindex function in script to select same value in multiple dropdown menus on the same webpage

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

The script with the below function only selects the set value in the first dropdown menu, but not the same value in the next dropdown menus on the same webpage. What adjustments do I need to make to make it select the same value in all next dropdown menus as well?

```
var size = "4";
function setSelectedIndex(s, v) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < s.options.length; i++ ) {
        if ( s.options[i].text == v ) {
            s.options[i].selected = true; 
            return; 
        }
    }
}
setSelectedIndex(document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0],size);
```

Comment: Do you want to convert it to jQuery, or keep as plain JS? You've tagged the question with jQuery, which should make this trivial.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Would like to keep as plain JS (removed the jQuery tag).

Comment: Like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/9Ab6p/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to iterate through the collection `getElementsByTagName` and call the `setSelectedIndex`

**Using javascript**

```
var size = "4";
function setSelectedIndex(s, v) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < s.options.length; i++ ) {
        if ( s.options[i].text == v ) {
            s.options[i].selected = true; 
            return; 
        }
    }
}

var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
for(i=0; i < selects.length; i++)
    setSelectedIndex(selects [i],size);
```

**Using jQuery**

Use the tag selector to get all the selects and then iterate through them using each(). Use the each again to get the option having text equal to `size` and select that option.

```
$('select').each(function(){
    $(this).find('option').each(function(){
         if($(this).text() == size)
            this.selected = true;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Adil for the quick reply. Quite new to this. Just to be sure: I keep the existing code and add your code below?

Comment: Check my updated answer, If you want you existing code then use the first solution. In second solution you do not need the setSelectedIndex